# Typing custom action type

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm following a design pattern from this talk (you don't need to watch it to understand my issue) :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gl3cCB_26M

The main concept is to give identifier to redux's type. For example an action creator for an api request should have a type like this : `[Books] API_REQUEST`. The action creator is basicaly combining `[Books]` and `API_REQUEST` then throw it as a type to it's own action. `[Books]` is given thought arguments of the action creator. It permit to do multiples api requests at the same time for multiples features and not confuse them in (for example) a middleware.

So this is simple in pure Javascript. But with Typescript we need to type our actions for our middlewares and reducers. The main idea of typing redux's actions is to do a `type: typeof API_REQUEST` so the action can be recognise by Typescript by it's type (according to this part of the doc: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript).

Now the issue is: how can I type an action (in this case for `API_REQUEST`) with a redux's type that is not recognisable by Typescript?

---

Here's a concrete example so you'll have a better understanding:

```js
// types/api.ts

export const API_REQUEST = 'API_REQUEST';
export const API_SUCCESS = 'API_SUCCESS';

interface ApiRequestAction {
  type: string; // can't be `typeof API_REQUEST` because the final action will be `[Books] API_REQUEST`
  payload: {
    body: object | null;
  };
  meta: {
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
    url: string;
    feature: string;
  };
}

interface ApiSuccessAction {
  type: string; // same as before
  payload: {
    data: object[];
  };
  meta: {
    feature: string;
  };
}

export type ApiActions = ApiRequestAction | ApiSuccessAction;
```

```js
// actions/api.ts

import { API_REQUEST, API_SUCCESS, ApiActions } from '../types/api';

export const apiRequest = ({ feature, body, method, url }): ApiActions => ({
  type: `${feature} ${API_REQUEST}`, // [Books] API_REQUEST
  payload: {
    body
  },
  meta: {,
    method,
    url,
    feature
  }
});

export const apiSuccess = ({ feature, data }): ApiActions => ({
  type: `${feature} ${API_SUCCESS}`, // [Books] API_SUCCESS
  payload: {
    data
  },
  meta: {
    feature
  }
});
```

```js
// reducer/books.ts

import { API_REQUEST, ApiActions } from '../types/api';

export const booksReducer = (state = [], action: ApiActions) => {

  if (action.type === `[Books] ${API_REQUEST}`) {
    // Here's the issue, Typescript can't be like "Alright, in this block action should be the same as decribed in ApiRequestAction because of the condition. So he'll have access to `action.payload.method` and all the others..."
    // But nop, he's just giving an error because he can't know if the action is the same a ApiRequestAction or ApiSuccessAction.
    // This is because I can't use `typeof` in ApiRequestAction because the type of the action can't be known before the action is created.
    // Then Typescript is throwing an error because he can't know what the action is. And so he can't know if `action.method.url` can be accessed because is only in one of the two possible actions.
    console.log(action.meta.url); // Property 'url' does not exist on type '{ feature: string; }'

    // Do some stuff with `action`
  }
}
```

So is there a way to fix this? I thought about some kind of Regex type intead of plain `string` (like: `type: /\[\w+\] API_REQUEST/`) but I don't think this is possible.

I hope this is understandable, it is pretty hard to explain. If you have any question, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Wandrille's answer I've did the following function that permit me to do the same comparison as in his answer but in a more adaptive way:

```js
function checkAction<T>(action: any, comparison: string): action is T {
    return action.type === comparison;
}

// And use it like so in my reducer / middleware
if (checkAction<ApiRequestAction>(action, `${feature} ${API_REQUEST}`)) {
  console.log(action.meta.url)
}
```

Comment: And I still don't know what is this `is` syntax

Comment: I have updated my answer with documentation fori `is`

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the interface with the following function:

```
export function isBooksRequest(action:any): action is ApiRequestAction {
  return action.type === `[Books] ${API_REQUEST}`; 
}

if (isBooksRequest(action)) {
  // action is considered as ApiRequestAction
  console.log(action.meta.url);
}
```

key word `is`, is a `typeof type guards`: check documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: What is this `action is ApiRequestAction` syntax? Never heard about it! And is there a way to make this function more adaptive? For example, is it possible to give `ApiRequestAction` and `API_REQUEST` via the arguments so the function can be used for any redux's type comparison? Maybe it is possible with a decorator?